# Creating DropDown by ComboBox1 and Filter the Desired Column

Tags: excel, vba

I have been using a sheet where i have created a manual drop down through "Data Validation" and was using this below code to filter the Column.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
 Dim lastrow As Long
 lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, "I").End(xlUp).Row
 With Me
 If Not Intersect(Target, .Range("I13")) Is Nothing Then
 If Target.Value <> "" Then
 .AutoFilterMode = False
 .Range("I15:I" & lastrow).AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:=Target.Value
 End If
 End If
 End With
End Sub
```

But now I'm trying to do an ActiveX program that loads the Unique value in ComboBox1 from given range and Filter column using the Value of the ComboBox1.

Here is the code which gets the unique values.
Problem is that i have tried to merge both codes to make it work for ComboBox1 but couldn't make it.

```
Dim v, e
With Sheets("Sheet1").Range("I16:I10000")
v = .Value
End With
With CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
.comparemode = 1
For Each e In v
If Not .exists(e) Then .Add e, Nothing
Next
If .Count Then Sheets("Sheet1").ComboBox1.List = Application.Transpose(.keys)
End With
```

I want to merge these both codes in one to work. I have tried but failed.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
 
 Dim lastrow As Long
 
 With Sheets("Sheet1").Range("I15:I" & lastrow)
    v = .Value
End With
With CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    .comparemode = 1
    For Each e In v
        If Not .exists(e) Then .Add e, Nothing
    Next
    If .Count Then Sheets("Sheet1").ComboBox1.List = Application.Transpose(.keys)
End With
 
 lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, "I").End(xlUp).Row
 
 With Me
 If Not Intersect(Target, .Range("I1")) Is Nothing Then
 If Target.Value <> "" Then
 .AutoFilterMode = False
.Range("I15:I" & lastrow).AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:=Target.Value
 End If
 End If
 End With
```

[image]

Comment: What problem are you facing?

Comment: Siddharth Rout, I want to merge them in one that both should work on (ByVal Target As Range)/Automate

Comment: Honestly, I have still not understood your requirement. Forget about merging for a moment. Can you explain what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Sir I actually i want that ComboBox1 load unique values from that range I12:I last row and when i select any value from ComboBox1 then Col"I" should be filter those similar  values which is available in ComboBox1.

Comment: I added an picture for example.

Comment: Understood. One moment.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226287/discussion-between-siddharth-rout-and-learning).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need the `Worksheet_Change` event anymore because you are not trapping the value from the data validation cell but from a `ComboBox1`. Paste this code (**Untested**) in the `Sheet1` code area. The below code will automatically filter when you select an item from the `ComboBox1`. If you want you can also use a `CommandButton` to run this code.

Let me know if you face an issue?

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Click()
    If ComboBox1.ListIndex = -1 Then Exit Sub
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Sheet1
        
    With ws
        .AutoFilterMode = False
        
        LastRow = .Range("I" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        
        .Range("I15:I" & LastRow).AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=ComboBox1.Value
    End With
End Sub
```

Also you need to load the `ComboBox1`. You can either do that using a `CommandButton` or you can use the `Workbook_Open()` event.